# predicted labels or predicted probabilities in a ROC plot?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

What should be taken as a parameter to plot ROC curves , for example in a classification model, I can get predicted labels and predicted probabilities.
I have softmax layer in the output layer.

Should I use predicted labels or predicted probabilities to plot ROC curve in a classification problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use the predicted labels.
Explanation - The ROC curve show possible classification performance at different setups.
Where 'classification performance' is a factor of True-positive-rate and False-positive-rate. And 'different setups' are thresholds used to determine a predicted label(class) based on predicted probability.
The latter is the reason why you should use predicted labels and not predicted probability.

Some additional context:
In my experience, ROC curve can be useful for three things:
1) Determining optimal setup(probability threshold) for a given model. Based on possible setups and problem needs.
2) Evaluating overall model performance and different models comparison. This can be achieved using the [AUC](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132777/what-does-auc-stand-for-and-what-is-it).
3) Understanding classification model behavior and identifying possible abnormalities. For example, if the curve has a step like pattern its possible your model is too simple.

Here is a [short nice explanation](https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/what-is-an-roc-curve/) on the ROC curve.

Comment: then it will like an discreet classifier if I consider labels only.For example the neural network model gives probability but random forest can also give prediction probabilities

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/268435/how-do-i-compute-the-spread-of-roc-curves also read this answer

Comment: I have seen many ROC plots in multi-class classification, if I use predicted labels than the plot would not be stair cased.